# Battery consumption between Monitiring and Ranging

Tags: ibeacon-android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

I am using Alt Beacon to monitor and range beacons. Monitoring always happens based on the foreground and background scan times. Once a region is entered, ranging is started and ranging is not stopped. I have the following questions about ranging
1. Does ranging still happen even if the beacon range is exited?
2. If ranging and monitoring is running will it consume more battery power?
3. Will battery consumption improve if ranging is stopped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it makes no difference on battery consumption whether you are monitoring or ranging what matters is if the app is in the foreground.

The [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) will do constant bluetooth scans while the app is in the foreground.  In the background it will do a scan for 10 seconds every five minutes (Android 4.3-4.4, actual intervals are configurable) and constant low power scans on Android 5+.

All of the above assumes you enable the [BackgroundPowerSaver](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html) as recommended with the library.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I assumed it is the same for monitoring and ranging.

Comment: Lookout for changes made due to Oreo - http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8 . Scans more frequent than 15 mins will not work.

Comment: While Oreo does change beacon detection times, battery consumption remains the same for both ranging and monitoring.